# Sulu: Is it possible to get a resized image with custom meassures without a image format

Tags: sulu

is it in sulu possoble to get a resized image on the fly with custom dimensions, without the need to define an image fomrat before? A kind of "dynamic image format".

Reason is, that I would like to define multiple versions of an image based on some code calculations in order to fill the srcset attribute of an image.

Thx a lot!
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by default, but you might be able to override some parts of the [`FormatManager`](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/develop/src/Sulu/Bundle/MediaBundle/Media/FormatManager/FormatManager.php#L211), but I am sure you would break some of Sulu's functionality that way (e.g. purging the cache for all image formats probably won't work anymore, or you can't manually crop that non-existing format). However, I have also not tested it, and I am not sure if that really works :-/